# find out every date from first to last day of the month using table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server

my assignment is to create table-valued function, which will have one DATETIME parameter and which returns every date from first to last day of the month, for example I gave the function date 04/12/2015 from that parameter and it will print all 31 days date of December.

I've already created 2 scalar functions (this was hint in assignment) one calculates first day

```
CREATE  FUNCTION firstday 
(
 @first DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
RETURN CAST(MONTH(@first) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + '01/' +  + CAST(YEAR(@first) AS VARCHAR)
END
```

and second calculates last day:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION lastday 
(
  @last DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
RETURN CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@last))),DATEADD(mm,1,@last)),101)
END
```

and here is the table-valued function but I don't know how to use that scalar functions within it

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_months_dates
(
   @mydate DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH Calender AS 
(
SELECT **first_function** AS CalenderDate
UNION ALL
SELECT CalenderDate + 1 FROM Calender
WHERE CalenderDate + 1 <= **last_function**
)
SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CalenderDate,25) 
FROM Calender
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I am using sql-server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're not here to do your homework for you, or it defeats the purpose of the homework.

That said, some tips to get you going -

- Don't build your FirstDay using a CAST to string like that - it's not reliable across different servers with different system settings. Run that on a non-US server and it'd fail. Use DATEADD and DATEPART instead.
- Look up numbers / tally tables. Combine that with DATEADD and you're away.
- Functions are called inline like anything else in a SELECT statement - so SELECT Function(Parameters) FROM Table

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
Declare @Date DATE = '20151104';

WITH X AS 
(
SELECT TOP (31)
       YEAR(@Date) AS [Year]
       ,MONTH(@Date) AS [Month]
       ,RIGHT('00' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) [Days]
FROM master..spt_values
), Dates AS
(
SELECT TRY_CONVERT ( DATE, ( CAST( [Year] AS varchar(4))
                           + CAST( [Month] AS varchar(2))
                           + CAST( [Days] AS varchar(2))) ) DatesVals
FROM X 
)
Select * FROM Dates
Where DatesVals IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: If we're going to do Lasha's homework in full rather than point them to how to do it, let's give best practice. This is SQL 2014, we can use DATEFROMPARTS - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213228.aspx

Comment: lol true well said didn't realize until you mentioned that it is a homework :)

Comment: @eftpotrm The approach I have used datefromparts wouldn't work as I am selecting top 31 from spt_values table and it will fail for month with less than 31 days.

Comment: That's another reason why I wouldn't do it that way. Handling errors is expensive, don't write code that'll throw errors in routine operation, and it's possible to cleanly do without here. But I'll leave Lasha something to do in the homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

This function will create a list of all dates in a month minus the format. You should be able to add it yourself:

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_get_months_dates
(
   @mydate DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH N(N)AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)),
tally(N)AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N.N)FROM N,N a)
SELECT top (day(EOMonth(@mydate))) 
    dateadd(d, N, EOMonth(@mydate, -1)) CalendarDate
FROM tally
ORDER BY N
```

Example of how to use function:

```
SELECT CalendarDate
FROM f_get_months_dates(getdate())
```

Result:

All dates within the current month

Answer (score -1):

You can try `DateAdd` function to get all the dates. Here is the example how to do it:

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.DatesBetween(@mydate date)
RETURNS @dates TABLE (
   DateValue date NOT NULL
) 
AS

BEGIN
declare  @startDate Date= dbo.firstday(@mydate);
declare  @endDate Date=dbo.lastday(@mydate);

   WHILE (@startDate <= @endDate) BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @dates VALUES (@startDate);
      SET @startDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @startDate);
   END;

   RETURN;
END;


select * from dbo.DatesBetween(GETDATE()) ;
```